# Information I need from the array is a level below the information I need to get

Tags: php, arrays, google-api

Sorry about the terrible title, I'm using the Google Geocoding API, but the format they use for the answer makes it difficult for me to catch the values into the right variables:

```
                  [address_components] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [long_name] => Estrada Silveira da Mota
                                [short_name] => Estr. Silveira da Mota
                                [types] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => route
                                    )

                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [long_name] => Posse
                                [short_name] => Posse
                                [types] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => political
                                        [1] => sublocality
                                        [2] => sublocality_level_1
                                    )
```

What I've been doing is to order by the first number:

```
  $rua = $json['results']['0']['address_components']['0']['short_name'];
```

But it varies, sometimes [0] is not the route, and then everything else goes out of order.
Is there a way I can order by the type but get the information in the short_name?

Comment: Looks like you are going to have to loop over the address_components array and first chcek for `types[0] == 'route' before collecting the data you actually want.

Comment: I thought about it I suposed looping would get way too confusing at a point since other than route there is street number, sublocality, and administrative areas and any one of those could be missing

Comment: This sounds a little odd for a Google generated output! I would expect them to make things a litle easier to use than that. Or am I looking through rose tinted glasses :) .... Oh yes ....  I am

Comment: Most of other API's have better outputs, but Google seems to get slightly better results, altough I still have other problems with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to write a loop for this:

This code might help:

```
foreach ($jsondata["results"] as $result) {
    foreach ($result["address_components"] as $address) {
        if (in_array("route", $address["types"])) {
            $street = $address["short_name"];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yea thats what I thought as well :)

Comment: I'll try to implement that

Comment: @JoaoNunes happy coding bro <3